# Can't reference to variable from other directory in terraform

Tags: variables, terraform, syntax-error

This is how it works rigth now:
I define variable and use them in ./terraformm/main.tf file:
 `variable "env_name" { type = string }`

`module "vpc"     {    source = "./modules/vpc"    env_name = var.env_name   }`

but i want to collect all variables in other file: ./terraform/environment/dev/variables.tf
so, i remove

`variable "env_name" { type = string }`

from ./terraformm/main.tf and add into ./terraform/environment/dev/variables.tf

and got a syntax error:
`no declaration found for "var.env_name"`

i do something wrong, but don't understand what =(

i already read terraforom documentation, but can't found any helpful information.

it's already described in subject.
i have a worked configuration but need changes to make it more accurate maybe.

Comment: terraform will only process and read files from one directory. So when you run terraform against the `terraformm/` dir which has main.tf it will only read the terraform files in there, it wont go off to look in other dirs or sub dirs

Answer (score 0):

Terraform only reads variables from the current directory.

What you can do is declare all shared variables in the root directory,
create modules for subfolders (if you haven't done that already), pass variables into the modules as inputs and define any specific module/environment-related variables inside the module configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In Terraform, each directory is a separate module, with its own variables, outputs, and locals.

You can then use your modules wherever you want by using `module` blocks.
You can see a module as a "black-box" that you only know has zero or more inputs (the variables), and zero or more outputs.

Likewise, you cannot access any of its internals from another module, even if it is a "parent" module (meaning this holds true even in case of nested modules structures).

---

Some useful documentation links:

- https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules
- https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/modules/module#what-is-a-terraform-module
- https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/structure